# Unity 3D c# yield return www hangs on particular URL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a strategy game in Unity, which communicates with server using HTTP, retrieving JSON objects via WWW requests. So far it has been working properly, however recently I've added a tester who is experiencing a strange problem. One of the URLs called by the registration process is hanging at the IEnumerator's "yield return www". The user tried two different machines and two different Internet providers, which suggests it's not environmental problem.

Here is the IEnumerator code:

```
    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
        addLogEntry("IEnumerator: "+www.url);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            addLogEntry("IEnumerator: " + www.url+" no error");
            // do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            addLogEntry("IEnumerator: " + www.url + " " + www.error);
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
```

The url returns the same value for all users and only one has this issue. There are no errors server side, there are no connectivity issues, since all other urls work fast on the same machine & client.

Does anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: What happens if he just visits the particular URL?

Comment: I haven't tried that, since it's not that simple, it takes POST data, so can't exactly tell him to put it in the browser.

It is a good point though, I'll have to check that, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit more of an issue, but I would indeed set something up using another bit of code or CURL or whatever to see if the problem still exists outside your code. Especially for such a one off.

Comment: I'll have it checked.

I have one theory regarding this problem, but I can't see two events connected. The only thing different with this URL and the rest, which are working fine, is that this one is loaded at the same time when iTween animation is launched (I have two onClick Listeners attached to a button, one launching animation, the other loading another url). I can't see how iTween would affect IEnumerator in another class, but that's the only difference I can see between what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I don't think iTween would cause any problems. You can just confirm it by disabling that animation. Would be great if you can report back with curl output or output from another tool such as http://requestmaker.com/ (Thanks Google).

Comment: We were both right, iTween was not responsible, but as I suspected it was related to the problem. After animating the object off the screen I turned it off, which killed the coroutine loading the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once i also encountered the same issue. At that time, the issue was that one URL was taking too much time in giving response. By the logic of my code, the GameObject on which monobehavior was attached and coorutine was running got disabled, causing the game object with the coroutine to die. I thought i should share the issue I had.

Comment: Ah! That is exactly what might be happening! I have the animation sliding the window off screen to have it deactivated. Timer for deactivation is 0.3s, which might be not enough for that tester, who is based across the ocean. I'll check it right away. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, the tester confirmed, increasing the delay between launching url load and turning off object fixed the problem. Thanks Umair!