# Failure to make rest calls with unity app on android

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a Unity cross platform mobile app we are using a external web api service. When calling this service in the unity editor, we get a 200 code and our json string is returned. However, when deploying the same app to the android platform, this call results in a 404 error.

With Android debugging i double checked all the parameters and headers and everything looks ok and the headers are exactly the same as on the editor on windows.

The android app has all network privileges. The network code is written in c# and does not use external DLL's. The only thing we use is the Web Api Kit Asset for easier building of webcalls (this asset still uses the normal Unity http framework)

Am I forgetting something? Any special parameters to make this work on android?

The api works in postman and requires https.

*Debug inspection*
[image]

Comment: Dude - post your code.  Just use a "www" call in Unity.

Comment: example .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349061